# How do you calculate the standard deviation for data which is mainly discrete but has a probability of being continuous?

Tags: statistics, probability, variance

I’m having some issue with calculating the standard deviation of a game. In the game you can get several different discrete scores. The scores have a fixed probability which is given. There is also a 5% chance that your score is randomly generated. You do not know the distribution of the random variable you are only given the mean and variance.

I’ve calculated the variance of the main game (ignoring the random variable) to be 5.2. The variance of the random variable is 137. From this I get a standard deviation of

sqrt(5.2 + 5% *137) = 3.47

Is this the correct method?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems like a Mixed Model or Generalized Linear Mixed Model for me. ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/glmm.htm